# Replace only works on first 2 list items

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, replace

I am using SharePoint 2013 in the cloud.  I have a page with a list WebPart that displays a view I setup that groups list items.  This creates an expandable tree view.

I am trying to remove the preceeding column name from each of the list items. The column name is **Group**, so each list items is displayed as **Group : Item** .  The column name and the list item value are both wrapped in links, so I need to remove the Group portion and the : that is left in the middle.

I am using the following code:

```
$("a:contains('Group')").closest("td").html( 
    function(index, text) {
        return text.replace(' : ', '&nbsp;');
    }
);
$("a:contains('Group')").html(
    function(index, text) {
        if(text.indexOf('Info') < 1) {
            return text.replace(/Group/, '&nbsp;');
        }
    }
);
```

The Group portion works fine.

I have used this code on another site with a similar page and it removes all the column names and colons.  When I do it on this page, it stops removing the colons after the 2nd list item.  For example

```
Group : Item 1
Group : Item 2
Group : Item 3
Group : Item 4
```

turns into

```
Item 1
Item 2
: Item 3
: Item 4
```

Comment: Is it possible your code is executing before the list web part has finished loading records? If you pull up the script console (F12) and manually run your JavaScript code after the page has loaded, does it remove the "Group : " prefices as expected?

Comment: I call the script after the body loads using _spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames. When the page loads, you can see if create the list and then remove the items.    When I do F12, I don't have a Script tab, not sure why.  I found the code, highlighted it and did "Run to Cursor". No change.

Comment: If you're using IE11, you should see a tab in the F12 developer tools labeled "Console" in which you can paste the code you want to execute.

Comment: Ahh... Got it.  For each item that still had the ":", I had to run the code snippet and then it disappeared. Do I need to put the function in some sort of loop?

Answer (score 1):

After trying a few methods for removing the unwanted text, I decided to change the column name value from "Group" to "Area".  Since the Page had "Group Info Wiki" on it and I was trying to prevent that "Group" text from changing, I had

```
if(text.indexOf('Info') < 1) {
      return text.replace(/Group/, '&nbsp;');
}
```

By removing the if statement part of the code, it fixed the problem.